# htaccess how to convert special chars

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to get a virable in PHP using $_GET, my .htaccess rewrites the url:

> localhost/arpege/gm/ TO localhost/arpege/index.php?code=gm

this is the code of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?code=$1
```

but when I'm typing localhost/arpege/p&p/ I'm only getting the first p using $_GET!

I want to get p&p using $_GET

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work, instead it took me to an incorrect url (Forbidden): http://localhost/D:/AppServ/www/arpege/index.php?code=p&p. Anyway, This won't convert the '&' to %26, would it?

Comment: You can try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?code=$1 [L,QSA,NE]` Moreover `'&' to  %26 conversion` happens in browser itself when you type URL manually. If it is part of the code then you can have URL like `localhost/arpege/p%26p/` programatically.